# History of ideas behind a bitcoin protocol

Tags: development, protocol, bitcoin-core-development

Could you outline the logical sequence of main ideas (concepts) that contributed to the evolution of the bitcoin protocol from the beginning
to now?

Comment: You may try to explore Bitcoin-Core versions history

Comment: Should we start with the Caesar cipher and the conch shell? This question is too broad.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick I learned Ceasar cipher in school :-) .Note the words "outline" and "main" in the question. These words should keep the answer narrower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitcoin is roughly defined by the 2009 [whitepaper](https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf). Long before, the idea of a trustless cryptographic money was discussed by [Wei Dai](http://www.weidai.com/bmoney.txt); however, Wei Dai couldn't solve the double spend problem, which delayed the creation of magic crypto money until 2008 (yes, the Satoshi client was created before the whitepaper)

Inspired by: [WeUseCoins.com](https://www.weusecoins.com/en/questions/#who-created-bitcoin)

Comment: Which old version? https://web.archive.org/web/20180512222930/https://www.weusecoins.com/de/

Comment: @Willtech I have updated the link.

Comment: I accepted this answer with references and hope I can take notes from that and ask more narrower question later. Thanks a lot.